# Setting properties Classpath Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, properties, classpath

I want to use log4j and so i wanted to set up a log4j.properties file

but now i get this message:

```
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
> (Logginger.Loggerlog4j). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system
> properly. log4j:WARN See
> http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

i've searched for this Error but i couldnt figure out how to do it in netbeans, only "Build classpath" in eclipse.

I dont use a Maven project!

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the directory where `log4j.properties` is located to your classpath.

Comment: thats my problem, i dont know how to set the classpath

Comment: @KyoAkashi lock [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.de/2006/06/set-classpath-in-eclipse-and-netbeans.html) maybe this helps.

Comment: i dont know if i'm simply to stupid for this or something...
but i cant get it to work...
everything i can add are .jar files
but no way to add .properties 
even if i make a .properties in my project by netbeans itself it wont work! :(

Comment: If you have opend the "Run Configuration" dialog --> select "Classpath" tab ---> select "User Entries". Then you can select the button "Advanced" on the right side. There you can select "Add Folder"